# Problema con Searchview android

Tags: java, android, searchview, arrayadapter

Bueno al problema, lo primero tengo un `Searchview` en mi `actionbar`.
Yo tengo un `listview` con un `arraydapter` personalizado el cual lo lleno con datos que me envían del webservices y yo por medio de la clase `Asynctask` lleno dicho listiview.

Inserte el `Searchview` ya que el usuario podrá buscar el cliente por el nombre, solo que ya implemente el Filter pero no me busca nada y no me manda error.

Quisiera que alguien me oriente a saber que es lo que me hace falta ingresar.

les dejo código mi **ArrayadApter**.

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> implements Filterable{

        List<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> original;
        List<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor>filtered;


        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> ArrayClientes) {
            super(context, 0, ArrayClientes);
            this.original = ArrayClientes;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor O_Cliente = getItem(position);

            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_cliente, parent, false);
            }

            //INICIALIZAR FORMAT
            DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombrecli)).setText(O_Cliente.getClienteDescripcion());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombrecli)).setTag(O_Cliente);

            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtsaldov)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_Cliente.getSaldoVencido()));
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtsaldot)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_Cliente.getSaldo()));

            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idcliente)).setText(String.valueOf(O_Cliente.getCliente()));
            //((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clienid)).setTag(O_Cliente);

            // Se almacena en settag el objeto Cliente
            convertView.setTag(O_Cliente);

            CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor item = getItem(position);

            //Devolver al ListView la fila creada
            return convertView;
        }
```

**Clase filter**

```
@Override
        public android.widget.Filter getFilter() {
            return new android.widget.Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    final FilterResults filterResults  = new FilterResults();
                    final ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> Values = new ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor>();
                    if(constraint != null && original!=null) {
                        int length=original.size();
                        int i=0;
                        while(i<length){
                            CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor item=original.get(i);
                            //do whatever you wanna do here
                            //adding result set output array

                            Values.add(item);

                            i++;
                        }
                        //following two lines is very important
                        //as publish result can only take FilterResults objects
                        filterResults.values = Values;
                        filterResults.count = Values.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    /*List<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> data = (List<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    clear();
                    addAll(data);
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();*/
                    original = (ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor>) results.values;
                    if (results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };

            };
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    /*List<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> data = (List<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    clear();
                    addAll(data);
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();*/
                    original = (ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor>) results.values;
                    if (results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
```

**Clase de objetos**

```
public class CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor implements Serializable {

    private int Empresa;
    private int Moneda;
    private int Cliente;
    private String ClienteDescripcion;
    private int Proveedor;
    private String ProveedorDescripcion;
    private double Saldo;
    private double SaldoVencido;



    public double Importe;
    public double Descuento;
    public double SubTotal;
    public double IVA;
    public double Total;

    String GPSLocation;
    String GPSLocation2;

    String Observacion;

    public CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor(int Empresa,
                                     int Moneda,
                                     int Cliente,
                                     String ClienteDescripcion,
                                     int Proveedor,
                                     String ProveedorDescripcion,
                                     double SaldoVencido,
                                     double Saldo)
    {
        super();
        this.Empresa = Empresa;
        this.Moneda = Moneda;
        this.Cliente = Cliente;
        this.ClienteDescripcion = ClienteDescripcion;
        this.Proveedor = Proveedor;
        this.ProveedorDescripcion = ProveedorDescripcion;
        this.Saldo = Saldo;
        this.SaldoVencido = SaldoVencido;

    }

    public int getEmpresa()
    {
        return Empresa;
    }
    public int getMoneda()
    {
        return Moneda;
    }
    public int getCliente()
    {
        return Cliente;
    }
    public String getClienteDescripcion()
    {
        return ClienteDescripcion;
    }
    public int getProveedor()
    {
        return Proveedor;
    }
    public String getProveedorDescripcion()
    {
        return ProveedorDescripcion;
    }
    public double getSaldo()
    {
        return Saldo;
    }
    public double getSaldoVencido() {
        return SaldoVencido;
    }

    public void setGPSLocation(String value)    {GPSLocation=value;}
    public String getGPSLocation() {return GPSLocation;}

    public void setGPSLocation2(String value)
    {
        GPSLocation2=value;
    }

    public String getGPSLocation2() {return GPSLocation2;}

    public void setObservacion(String value)
    {
        Observacion = value;
    }
    public String getObservacion(){return Observacion;}

    public String toLowerCase(Locale aDefault) {
        return null;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return ClienteDescripcion;
    }
```

### Edit: Solución

Después de investigar y de hacer pruebas, por fin logre solucionar el problema a a esta pregunta, que era que no me funcionaba, les dejo la solución que solo fue una una linea de código.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cliente, menu);

        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search));
            searchView.setMaxWidth(2129960);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    adaptador.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                    System.out.println("on text submit text: " + query);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Alguien que me ayude?

Comment: Hugo yo te ayudo pero agrega una imagen de lo que estas realizando. Imagino en el filter se agregan los datos y al dar click busca la palabra seleccionada?

Comment: Muchas gracias Elenasys, ya pude solucionarlo

Comment: Excelente me da mucho gusto, agrega tu respuesta! =)

Comment: listo ya,,, abrire otro debate tengo un detalle con mi listview.. lo que pasa es que cuando yo filtro una zona y esa zona no trae cliente quiero mi listview se borren los datos que estaba mostrando

Comment: Elenasys estas??? necesito de tu ayuda

Comment: tengo otro problema pero no sabia como contactarte, ya abri el debate

Comment: por cierto agrega tu respuesta para que la vean otros desarrolladores.

Comment: si la agregue, crees que me puedas ayudar con mi otro debate?

Comment: Pudiste solucionarlo? Puedo ayudarte, pero pasa el link del otro del debate!